# FluentValidation NotEqual client side rule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to add the NotEqual client-side rule to my MVC 5 project found [here](https://gist.github.com/timhobbs/3896651).

It all seems to be working except I can't seem to get to the error message that is passed into the rule. I can see it in a private field in the debugger, I'm just not sure how to get to it in the `GetClientValidationRules` method. The issue is on the line where it builds the error message, `validator.ErrorMessageSource.GetString()` doesn't exist anymore.

```
public class NotEqualClientRule : FluentValidationPropertyValidator 
{
  public static ModelValidator Create(ModelMetadata meta, ControllerContext context, PropertyRule propertyDescription, IPropertyValidator validator) 
  {
    return new NotEqualClientRule(meta, context, propertyDescription, validator);
  }

  public NotEqualClientRule(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext, PropertyRule propertyDescription, IPropertyValidator validator) : base(metadata, controllerContext, propertyDescription, validator) 
  {
    ShouldValidate = false; //This is necessary - don't want to kick in during model binding.
  }

  public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules() 
  {
    if (!this.ShouldGenerateClientSideRules()) 
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var validator = Validator as NotEqualValidator;

    var errorMessage = new MessageFormatter()
        .BuildMessage(validator.ErrorMessageSource.GetString());

    var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule 
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
        ValidationType = "notequal"
    };

    if (validator.MemberToCompare != null) 
    {
        rule.ValidationParameters["field"] = String.Format("#{0}", validator.MemberToCompare.Name);
    } 
    else 
    {
        rule.ValidationParameters["field"] = validator.ValueToCompare;
    }

    yield return rule;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
var errorMessage = new MessageFormatter().BuildMessage(validator.ErrorMessageSource.GetString());
```

to

```
var formatter = new MessageFormatter().AppendPropertyName(Rule.PropertyName);
string errorMessage = formatter.BuildMessage(validator.Options.ErrorMessageSource.GetString(null));
```

got me the error message that I set up in the validation rule.